# Fluentd on Openshift?

Tags: openshift

Is it possible (without too much trouble) to run Fluentd on Openshift?  As a regular cartridge or even as an embeddable cartridge?

I wish to send logging information off my Openshift gear(s) to my own machine(s) that will also be running Fluentd.

Just as a Java or PHP application can have an embedded database, it would be nice to have an embedded centralised logging system.

This isn't meant to be just for development, it's the way I will capture and analyse events in the application.

Thanks

Comment: I've searched extensively and there seems like a proposal (PEP?) for use of (r)syslog but I can't see any evidence of even that and I'm looking for something more powerful and flexible, hence fluentd.